# set variable in nginx conf json

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to set the below header in nginx conf

`payload="{\"pathParameters\":{\"additionalProp1\":\"string\",\"additionalProp2\":\"string\",\"additionalProp3\":\"string\"},\"operationId\":\"operation\",\"scope\":\"Apps\"}"`

more_set_input_headers payload $payload;

but I am getting below error :
/etc/nginx $ nginx -s reload
2021/03/17 04:36:41 [emerg] 2463#2463: unexpected "p" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:593
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "p" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:593

Comment: You are using `openresty` or `nginx`?

Comment: nginx I am using

Comment: The direct you have used is not available in nginx by default https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/. Also variables are not create using `X=Z`, it needs `set $X Z`

Comment: I am using set to define the payload variable 

set payload "{\"pathParameters\":{\"additionalProp1\":\"string\",\"additionalProp2\":\"string\",\"additionalProp3\":\"string\"},\"operationId\":\"operation\",\"scope\":\"Apps\"}";

but till getting the error

Comment: It needs to be `set $payload <value>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use below code to set the variable value

```
set $payload <value>
```